# C++ String comparison with same size and content returns false

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm having a problem when I'm trying to compare a string resulted from a function, with a string that is manually declared:

```
string ip = "3.3.333.33";

string cuxa(){

    HINTERNET hInternet, hFile;
    DWORD rSize;
    char buffer[47];

    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hFile = InternetOpenUrlA(hInternet, "https://www.myexternalip.com/raw", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    InternetReadFile(hFile, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), &rSize);
buffer[rSize] = '\0';

    InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    return buffer;
}
```

So basically , when I'm doing a simple

```
if(cuxa() == ip){ cout << "false"; }
```

=> won't return anything because that comparison is false.

They both have equal sizes , same string content but I just can't get it to work.

I'd appreciate any suggestions , thank you!

Comment: Are you sure they are exactly the same?  Do `std::string some_name  = cuxa();` then print `some_name` to make sure it looks like `ip`.

Comment: @NathanOliver thats what I meant by same content

Comment: `buffer[rSize] = '\0';` looks like a potential for UB. What happens if `InternetReadFile()` read 47 characters into your buffer?

Comment: @an4rei _"=> won't return anything because"_ Shouldn't `if(cuxa() == ip){ cout << "false"; }` print nothing if the results actually match? What do you mean _return something_?

Comment: @drescherjm a safer option is to use `return string(buffer, rSize);` instead, then you don't have to insert a null terminator at all

Comment: `3.3.333.33` is not a valid IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when `www.myexternalip.com` reports the IP address, it has a trailing newline at the end of it.

Example output:

> 10.04.56.14/n

To fix your issue, just overwrite the newline with a null terminating character.

```
buffer[rSize-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: You should check to make sure the newline is actually present before you remove it, eg: `if (buffer[rSize-1] == '\n') buffer[rSize-1] = '\0'; return buffer;`  Alternatively: `if (buffer[rSize-1] == '\n') --rSize; return string(buffer, rSize);`